# How to retrieve IP addresses of possible ssh attackers?

Tags: ssh, scripting, security

I've just `cat /var/log/auth.log` log and see, that there are many `| grep "Failed password for"` records.

However, there are two possible record types - for valid / invalid user. It complicates my attempts to `| cut` them.

I would like to see create a list (text file) with IP addresses of possible attackers and number of attempts for each IP address. Is there any easy way to create it?

Also, regarding only `ssh`: What all records of `/var/log/auth.log` should I consider when making list of possible attackers?

Example of my 'auth.log' with hidden numbers:

```
cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "Failed password for" | sed 's/[0-9]/1/g' | sort -u | tail
```

Result:

```
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user ucpss from 111.11.111.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user vijay from 111.111.11.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user webalizer from 111.111.11.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user xapolicymgr from 111.111.11.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user yarn from 111.111.11.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user zookeeper from 111.111.11.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for invalid user zt from 111.11.111.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for mysql from 111.111.11.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for root from 111.11.111.111 port 11111 ssh1
Mar 11 11:11:11 vm11111 sshd[111]: Failed password for root from 111.111.111.1 port 11111 ssh1
```

Comment: I suggest you create ssh keys, install them up on your server and disable passwords entirely in your server sshd config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ... lookup settings `PasswordAuthentication no` and `PermitRootLogin without-password`  ... then all such password attempts will be thwarted before ever entering the auth.log ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
grep "Failed password for" /var/log/auth.log | grep -Po "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" \
| sort | uniq -c
```

It greps for the string `Failed password for` and extracts (`-o`) the ip address. It is sorted, and `uniq` counts the number of occurences.

The output would then look like this (with your example as input file):

```
  1 111.111.111.1
  3 111.11.111.111
  6 111.111.11.111
```

The last one in the output has tried 6 times.

Comment: this is the best answer @chaos - added to my box of useful oneliners - thanks!

Comment: Great solution. I didn't know that grep can extract regex matches, not just filter lines. I've just added `| sort -n` to the chain.

Comment: Good answer - multiple greps are usually a sign to use sed. `sed -nr '/Failed/{s/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/;p}'` replaces both greps.

Comment: @orion true but imagine that the first grep can also be `zgrep "Failed" /var/log/auth.log*` to also search trough the compressed log archives, what `sed` cannot.

Comment: What about IPv6?

Answer (score 7):

It might be a bloated solution but i suggest you look at installing something like [Fail2Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban)

It is made for this kind of logging + adds the bonus of being able to add (temporary) rules in your firewall to block repeating offenders. Be sure to whitelist your own ip's though, i managed to lock myself out temporarily on a few occasions

Comment: Well, nice commentary, but not a answer to the question. It's more like suggestion that could remove the need of question, but I don't need a daemon to monitor my files. I've got my reasons why do I need to make that list as text file just by scripts.  :)

Comment: I agree with @Miro, had you not mentioned it here I'd have added it in a comment.

Comment: @Miro, you're right, not an answer to the question itself, it just came to mind as a convenient tool for this kind of logging.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "Failed password for" /var/log/auth.log |
    awk -F"from" {'print $2'} |
    awk {'print $1'} |
    sort -u
```

Comment: The result is `password` - not working. It doesn't even cover different entry types, `awk` print column is alternative to the `cut`, not the solution.

Comment: It works for me either with sample above ou real /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Well, it didn't work before the edit - when the comment had been made. Now it works correctly. However, it misses `uniq -c` as in the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out real well for me.  (IPs have been changed to protect the guilty)

```
$ awk '/Failed/ {x[$(NF-3)]++} END {for (i in x){printf "%3d %s\n", x[i], i}}' /var/log/auth.log | sort -nr
 65 10.0.0.1
 14 10.0.0.2
  4 10.0.0.3
  1 10.0.0.4
```