# How to retrieve counts of IP addresses from log file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, logs, ip

I am checking a log file to retrieve ip adresses plus how many times a log failed. This is what my log file looks like:

```
Feb  2 15:20:02 tank sshd[14870]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 13356 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:07 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:12 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:16 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:20 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:23 tank sshd[14874]: Accepted password for root from 143.100.67.173
```

Now, I want to also check for how many times the log was accepted. The idea is to get an overview over brute forcing attacks.

How do I extend

```
sed -nr '/Failed/{s/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/;p}'| sort | uniq -c
```

to also check for accepted passwords? Something like

```
sed -nr '/Accepted|Failed/{s/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/;p}'| sort | uniq -c
```

But instead of having an "or" between Accepted and Failed I would like to get a count result that would look like this:

```
123.53.163.22 3 2
```

(The columns are: IP address, total Failed, total Accepted)

This is related to [How to retrieve IP addresses of possible ssh attackers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190907/how-to-retrieve-ip-addresses-of-possible-ssh-attackers/485575#485575)

Comment: From the command that you have, we can guess what your input might look like.   We don't like to guess.   Show a representative example of what your input looks like and what output you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the scant sample ....

```
cat horbaje
Feb  2 15:20:02 tank sshd[14870]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 13356 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:07 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:12 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:16 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:20 tank sshd[14874]: Failed password for root from 143.100.67.173 port 30595 ssh2
Feb  2 15:20:23 tank sshd[14874]: Accepted password for root from 143.100.67.173
```

This, I think, does what you want:

```
awk '$6~/Failed/{a[$11][1]++}; $6~/Accepted/{a[$11][2]++} END{for(i in a){printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",i,a[i][1],a[i][2]}}' horbaje
143.100.67.173  5   1
```

Comment: Thank you tink, that was very helpful in solving my problem!

Comment: Pleased to hear =}

Comment: Follow up question.If I want to find the ip adress not by position how would I replace a[$11][1] with something like reg ex: a(d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) ?

Comment: I'd do something like this: `awk '{ip=gensub(/.* from ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/,"\\1","1",$0);print ip} $6~/Failed/{a[ip][1]++}; $6~/Accepted/{a[ip][2]++} END{for(i in a){printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",i,a[i][1],a[i][2]}}{}ip=""' horbaje`